# Android GLES 2 draw line flicker and strange effects

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, glsles

I am trying to draw some 3d lines in android using gles 2. But it resulted in some strange effects. Flicker happens when i rotate the scene/camera. But not only that, there is also some lines drawn in 2d (sometime dots) at random. This is the screenshot:
[image]

While this image shows no problem at all (using different camera angle):
[image]

I've also tried to use GLES 1 to draw these lines and it worked (no flicker or random lines). Perhaps it have something to do with the shader code? The vertex shader was taken from android gles example which is very simple.

Update:
After some more tries, I found that this only happens when the camera yaw (y axis rotary) is more than 90 degree. Within range of 0-90 yaw, the lines display normally.
What am I doing wrong?
I'm running the program on Galaxy Tab S with android v4.4.2.

Here is the whole code used to reproduce the erroneous image:

Main activity:

```
package com.mycompany.bug_test;

import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class OpenGLES20Activity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private GLSurfaceView mGLView = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if ( mGLView == null ) {
            mGLView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
        }
        setContentView(mGLView);
    }
}
```

Surface view:

```
package com.mycompany.bug_test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

    private final MyGLRenderer mRenderer;

    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

        mRenderer = new MyGLRenderer();
        setRenderer(mRenderer);
    }

    private final float TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR = 360.0f;
    private float mPreviousX;
    private float mPreviousY;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {

        float x = e.getX();
        float y = e.getY();

        int action_type = e.getAction();
        if ( action_type ==  MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE ) {
            float dx = x - mPreviousX;
            float dy = y - mPreviousY;

            final float div_mag = 10;
            float min_dx = dx;
            if ( min_dx > (getRootView().getWidth()/div_mag) ) {min_dx = (getRootView().getWidth()/div_mag);}
            if ( min_dx < -(getRootView().getWidth()/div_mag) ) {min_dx = -(getRootView().getWidth()/div_mag);}
            float min_dy = dy;
            if ( min_dy > (getRootView().getHeight()/div_mag) ) {min_dy = (getRootView().getHeight()/div_mag);}
            if ( min_dy < -(getRootView().getHeight()/div_mag) ) {min_dy = -(getRootView().getHeight()/div_mag);}

            float new_yaw = (  mRenderer.cam_yaw - (min_dx * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR / getRootView().getWidth())  ) % 360;
            float new_pitch = mRenderer.cam_pitch + (min_dy * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR / getRootView().getHeight());
            if ( new_pitch > 89 ) {
                new_pitch = 89;
            }
            if ( new_pitch < -89 ) {
                new_pitch = -89;
            }


            synchronized (mRenderer.CAM_LOCK) {
                mRenderer.cam_yaw = new_yaw;
                mRenderer.cam_pitch = new_pitch;
            }
            System.out.println("Yaw=" + new_yaw + "   Pitch=" + new_pitch);
        }

        mPreviousX = x;
        mPreviousY = y;
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the most important part, GL renderer:

```
package com.mycompany.bug_test;

import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.Matrix;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private final String vertexShaderCode =
            "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
            "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
            "void main() {" +
            "   gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
            "}";

    private final String fragmentShaderCode =
            "precision mediump float;" +
            "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
            "void main() {" +
            "   gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
            "}";

    private int mProgram;

    private int mMVPMatrixHandle;
    private int mPositionHandle;
    private int mColorHandle;



    private final float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];
    float viewAspect;
    float fovy = 45;
    float fovx = 45;

    final Object CAM_LOCK = new Object();
    float cam_pos_x = 0;
    float cam_pos_y = 0;
    float cam_pos_z = 0;
    float fcs_pos_x = 0;
    float fcs_pos_y = 0;
    float fcs_pos_z = 0;
    //Try Yaw=246.22672   Pitch=21.992342 with cam_focus_range = 175 to get visible error.
    float cam_pitch = 21.992342f;
    float cam_yaw = 246.22672f;
    float cam_focus_range = 175;



    final float line_gap = 100;
    final float line_length = 6000;

    private final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
    private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private int vertexCount = 0;


    public MyGLRenderer() {
        float[] GMrkLines = new float[(int)( (line_length / line_gap) + 1 ) * 2 * 2 * COORDS_PER_VERTEX ];

        int __P = 0;
        for (int ln=0; ln<( (line_length / line_gap) + 1 ); ln++) {
            GMrkLines[__P++] = (float)(line_length /2);                             //x
            GMrkLines[__P++] = 0;                                                   //y
            GMrkLines[__P++] = (float)(line_gap *ln - line_length /2);              //z
            vertexCount++;
            GMrkLines[__P++] = (float)(-line_length /2);                            //x
            GMrkLines[__P++] = 0;                                                   //y
            GMrkLines[__P++] = (float)(line_gap *ln - line_length /2);              //z
            vertexCount++;

            GMrkLines[__P++] = (float)(line_gap *ln - line_length /2);              //x
            GMrkLines[__P++] = 0;                                                   //y
            GMrkLines[__P++] = (float)(line_length /2);                             //z
            vertexCount++;
            GMrkLines[__P++] = (float)(line_gap *ln - line_length /2);              //x
            GMrkLines[__P++] = 0;                                                   //y
            GMrkLines[__P++] = (float)(-line_length /2);                            //z
            vertexCount++;
        }

        System.out.println("Vertex count=" + vertexCount);

        {
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(GMrkLines.length * 4);
            bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
            vertexBuffer.put(GMrkLines);
            vertexBuffer.position(0);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
        int vertexShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);
        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader);
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);

        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");
        mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

        GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, new float[]{0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1}, 0);


        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        GLES20.glEnable( GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST );
        GLES20.glDepthFunc( GLES20.GL_LEQUAL );
        GLES20.glLineWidth(4);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
        float _cam_pos_x;
        float _cam_pos_y;
        float _cam_pos_z;
        float _fcs_pos_x;
        float _fcs_pos_y;
        float _fcs_pos_z;
        float _cam_pitch;
        float _cam_yaw;
        synchronized (CAM_LOCK) {
            _cam_pos_x = cam_pos_x;
            _cam_pos_y = cam_pos_y;
            _cam_pos_z = cam_pos_z;
            _fcs_pos_x = fcs_pos_x;
            _fcs_pos_y = fcs_pos_y;
            _fcs_pos_z = fcs_pos_z;
            _cam_pitch = cam_pitch;
            _cam_yaw = cam_yaw;
        }


        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


        _fcs_pos_x = 0;
        _fcs_pos_y = 0;
        _fcs_pos_z = 0;
        _cam_pos_y = (float) ( _fcs_pos_y + (cam_focus_range * Math.sin( Math.toRadians(_cam_pitch) )));
        double cam_to_focus_horz = cam_focus_range * Math.cos( Math.toRadians(_cam_pitch) );
        _cam_pos_x = (float) ( _fcs_pos_x + (cam_to_focus_horz * Math.cos( Math.toRadians(_cam_yaw) )));
        _cam_pos_z = (float) ( _fcs_pos_z + (cam_to_focus_horz * Math.sin( Math.toRadians(_cam_yaw) )));

        Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, _cam_pos_x, _cam_pos_y,_cam_pos_z, _fcs_pos_x, _fcs_pos_y, _fcs_pos_z, 0, 1, 0);


        {
            float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
            Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);

            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                    vertexStride, vertexBuffer);
            GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_LINES, 0, vertexCount);

            GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
        if (height <= 0) { // avoid a divide by zero error!
            height = 1;
        }
        viewAspect = (float) width / (float) height;
        fovx = fovy * viewAspect;

        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        GLU_perspective(mProjectionMatrix, 0, fovy, viewAspect, 1.0f, 8000.0f);
    }


    public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode) {
        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

        int[] _param = new int[4];
        GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, _param, 0);
        System.out.println("Shader no : " + shader);
        System.out.println("Compile status = " + _param[0] + "   (GL_TRUE=" + GLES20.GL_TRUE + ")");
        System.out.println("ERR : " + GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader));

        return shader;
    }

    void GLU_perspective(float[] RetMtx, int offset, float fovY, float aspect, float zNear, float zFar)
    {
        float fW, fH;

        fH = (float) (Math.tan(fovY / 360 * Math.PI) * zNear);
        fW = fH * aspect;

        Matrix.frustumM(RetMtx, offset, -fW, fW, -fH, fH, zNear, zFar );
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried to change precision to highp for both shader, but there is no change (still flickering). Has anyone tried my code on different environment? Please tell if you also encountered this issue on different environment. This will rule out the blame on the environment.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem especially with Samsung devices (I had 3 of them showing the same issues).
It turned out that drawing lines with GL_LINE_STRIP or GL_LINES results in the artefacts and flickering that you show in your screenshots. But only if the line traverses the camera plane and only if the first coordinate of the line is behind the camera's plane and the second coordinate is in front of the camera's plane. When it's the other way round - no problem.

In my opinion this does not make sense at all and thus seems to be a driver problem - there is no error in your code.

As a workaround I let the vertex shader detect this constellation and then flip the vertices. Detection is done by checking the sign of the matrice's z-scaling component [2][2]. In my case the vertices are {0,0,1} and {0,0,-1} - so flipping can easily be done by negating the vertex values.

```
// Vertex shader snippet
cPosition = vPosition;
voMatrix = viewMatrix * objMatrix;
if ( voMatrix [2][2] < 0.0 ) cPosition = -vPosition;
```

I hope this helps (even if the answer comes in quite late).